# PSQL different results when redirecting output

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql, postgresql-9.6

I'm having the weirdest problem.
We have a plpgsql script running through a cron job. It loops through a series of records and updates other records based on them. After that, it inserts a record in a logging table, informing how many records it affected.
Here's what's weird: If we redirect the output to /dev/null, the script runs but it doesn't affect any record. If we don't redirect, it works correctly.

Here's how the crontab line reads:

> */10 * * * * psql -Upostgres -d pje_pi_2g -f /root/atos2g.sql >/dev/null

Here's the script:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE mudar record ; qt INT = 0 ;
BEGIN
    FOR mudar IN SELECT
        vi.id_,
        pd.id_processo_documento
    FROM
        jbpm_variableinstance vi
    JOIN jbpm_processinstance pi ON pi.id_ = vi.processinstance_
    AND pi.end_ IS NULL
    JOIN core.tb_processo_instance ppi ON ppi.id_proc_inst = pi.id_
    JOIN jbpm_taskinstance ti ON ti.procinst_ = pi.id_
    AND ti.end_ IS NULL
    AND ti.name_ IN (
        'Cumprir determinações [CD]',
        'Cumprir determinações (urgência) [CD]',
        'Ato judicial assinado [PREC]',
        'Processos recebidos sem cálculo [PREC]',
        'Triagem (financeiro) [PREC]',
        'Triagem (secretaria) [PREC]',
        'Triagem (cálculo) [PREC]',
        'Cumprir determinações [CDPREC]',
        'Acórdão assinado [BC2G]',
        'Lançar movimentações do julgamento [DCG2G]'
    )
    JOIN core.tb_processo prc ON prc.id_processo = ppi.id_processo
    JOIN core.tb_processo_documento pd ON pd.id_processo = prc.id_processo
    AND pd.id_processo_documento = (
        SELECT
            pd1.id_processo_documento
        FROM
            core.tb_processo_documento pd1
        JOIN core.tb_processo_documento_bin bin ON  pd1.id_processo_documento_bin = bin.id_processo_documento_bin
        JOIN client.tb_proc_doc_bin_pess_assin ass ON bin.id_processo_documento_bin = ass.id_processo_documento_bin
        JOIN client.tb_pessoa_magistrado pm ON pm. ID = ass.id_pessoa
        WHERE
            pd1.id_processo = prc.id_processo
        ORDER BY
            pd1.dt_juntada DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
    WHERE
        vi.name_ = 'pje:atoProferido'
    AND vi.longvalue_ <> pd.id_processo_documento loop 
        qt := qt + 1 ; 
        UPDATE jbpm_variableinstance
    SET longvalue_ = mudar.id_processo_documento
    WHERE
        id_ = mudar.id_ ;
    END loop ; 
    INSERT INTO tjpi.tb_scripts_log (ds_script, qt_afetados)
    VALUES
        ('Atos proferidos', qt) ;
    END ;
```

If we run it like that, it doesn't loop through any lines. If we remove the redirection, it loops correctly.
Does anybody know what we should be lookin for?
In time: Id we try to run the psql command manually, it still only works without redirecting.
Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long question.

Comment: I would check either the postgres main log. Or with cron jobs in the past, I've debugged by checking the mail the cron job sends you. It will tell you if there is an error. I'd try adding a space between `-U` and `postgres` in your crontab line. Not sure if that will make a difference

Comment: Furthermore, `postgres` user may not have permissions to write into that location.

Comment: It's running as root. It cancelada write to /Dev/null.

Comment: Yes the cron job is running as root but postgres needs permission to write there since the output is coming from postgres.